# Android Studio, overlapping text with Project Name

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I just started with Android development on mac. I just wrote this peace of code in content_main.xml. Here the code is overlapping.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter Your Name"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_name" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Confirm Name"
    android:onClick="confirmName"/>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/okhfA.png]

Looking for sincere help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you attach any image? Can't see.

Comment: are you sure you have (View v) as argument on the method youa re calling on click?

Comment: @Mohammad - I think I know the issue, but we need to see the image. It was not attached correctly.

Comment: @Mohammad  post your activity_main.xml file also

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the image, I believe this will solve your issue. I think the toolbar is covering your EditText

Enter the two lines of code into the LinearLayout block.

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

The LinearLayout block should now look like this.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp">
```